# Passing Negative Numbers into Getopt

Tags: c++, getopt, negative-number

I need to pass negative numbers into getopt and I was wondering if there is a simple way to change the prefix used by getopt (i.e. '-' character to flag in the case statement) into a different character like '--' or '+'.

Do I need to use Getopt::Long to change the prefix?

Answer (score 2):

Using `--` (e.g. `yourcommand <actual options> -- -5`) will allow you to pass negative arguments in cases where you don't have control of the code. The [man page for getopt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) states

> The special argument "--" forces an end of option-scanning regardless of the scanning mode.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a way to change the command line argument prefix to be anything other than `-` (or `--` when using `getopt_long()`). However, if you need to pass a negative number, you should define the argument as 'required_argument'. For example, here's a short GetOpt method that uses the `getopt_long_only` method to get the command line arguments:

```
// personaldetails.cpp

// compile with:
// g++ -std=c++11 personaldetails.cpp -o personaldetails
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <getopt.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Define some variables
    std::string name = "" ;
    int age = 0 ;
    double weight = 0.0 ;

    // Setup the GetOpt long options.
    std::vector<struct option> longopts ;
    longopts.push_back({"Name",  required_argument, 0, 'N'}) ; 
    longopts.push_back({"Age",   required_argument, 0, 'A'}) ; // <- IMPORTANT
    longopts.push_back({"Weight",required_argument, 0, 'W'}) ; // <- IMPORTANT
    longopts.push_back({0,0,0,0}) ;

    // Now parse the options
    while (1)
    {
        int c(0) ;
        int option_index = -1;

        c = getopt_long_only (argc, argv, "A:N:W:",
                              &longopts[0], &option_index);

        /* Detect the end of the options. */
        if (c == -1) break;

        // Now loop through all of the options to fill them based on their values
        switch (c)
        {
            case 0:
                /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
                break ;
            case '?':
                // getopt_long_omly already printed an error message.
                // This will most typically happen when then an unrecognized
                // option has been passed.
                return 0 ;
            case 'N':
                name = std::string(optarg) ;
                break ;
            case 'A':
                age = std::stoi(optarg) ;
                break ;
            case 'W':
                weight = std::stod(optarg) ;
                break ;
            default:
                // Here's where we handle the long form arguments
                std::string opt_name( longopts[option_index].name ) ;
                if (opt_name.compare("Name")==0) {
                    name = std::string(optarg) ;
                } else if (opt_name.compare("Age")==0) {
                    age = std::stoi(optarg) ;
                } else if (opt_name.compare("Weight")==0) {
                    weight = std::stod(optarg) ;
                }
                break ;
        }
    }

    // Print the persons details
    std::cout << "Name  : " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Age   : " << age << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Weight: " << weight << std::endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The key part here is that in `longopts` I've set the parameters I'm going to convert to integer and double to have `required_argument`. This tells GetOpt to *expect* another parameter after you've declared it on the command line. This means that GetOpt will read in the argument after your command line parameter as the argument *to that command line parameter*. For the case where we want to pass the single `char` argument (i.e. `-N`, `-A`, or `-W`), this is where passing `"N:A:W:"` to getopt is important. The `:` basically does the same thing for the single char parameter as `required_argument` does for the long form.

Running the script I can do:

```
$ ./personaldetails -Name Sally -Age -45 -Weight 34.5
Name  : Sally
Age   : -45
Weight: 34.5

$./personaldetails -N Sally -A -45 -W -34.5
Name  : Sally
Age   : -45
Weight: -34.5
```

Note that because the script uses `getopt_long_only()` I can pass the long form of the argument parameters with a single `-`.